# cargar imagen mediante ajax en symfony5

Tags: ajax, symfony5

queria cargar una imagen mediante ajax en symfony pero no se como añadir el `asset` mediante ajax.
esto es el ajax:

```
$(document).on("change",'.color', function(event) { 
        var Ruta=Routing.generate("colores_ajax");
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:Ruta,
        data: {color: $('.color:checked').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#foto").attr('src',  asset(response['imagenAjax'])); 
            $("#precio").html(response['precioAjax']);
            $("#comprar").attr('href', Routing.generate('comprar', {'id': response.productoAjax}));
        }
    });
    });
```

y esto la imagen en twig:

```
<img id="foto" class= "border productoPaginaPrincipal" src="{{ asset(producto.imagen) }}">
```

todo carga bien exepto la imagen.

Comment: Esto: `asset(response['imagenAjax'])` no funciona de la forma que crees. Estás mezclando 2 funciones que se ejecutan en ámbitos muy distintos.

Comment: y como se solucionaria?

Comment: he probado con esto pero tampoco:he probado con esto pero tampoco: `$("#foto").attr('src',  "asset('"+response['imagenAjax']+"')");`

Comment: finalmente lo he conseguido siguiento estas instrucciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163803/how-to-get-assets-img-url-in-symfony-controller